# Is it possible to delete part of a match with Regex C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to **scrape** a web, i get the `<tr>` of a table but then i have to remove the `<tr>` part to get only the `<td>`s. Is there any way to delete the `<tr....>` part and `</tr>` without doing substrings or replace?

```
var location = Regex.Match(row.Value, "<tr data-title=\"Location\"(.*?)tr>").Value;
location = location.Replace("<tr data-title=\"Location\">", "");
location = location.Replace("</tr>", "").Trim();
```

I'm trying to achieve this: for example a `<tr>` that contains `<tr clas="lala"...><td>..</td></tr>` i want to get only `<td>...</td>`

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? I think you can either remove the stuff you don't want (`Regex.Replace`, `string.Replace`) or keep the stuff you want (`Regex.Match`).

Comment: Take `.Groups[1].Value` instead of `.Value`.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this: for example a `<tr>` that contains `<tr clas="lala"...><td>..</td></tr>` i want to get only `<td>...</td>`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use regular expressions to parse html. Take some html parser.

Second, the value you need is captured in the group. Just take him out of the group.

```
var location = Regex.Match(row.Value, "<tr data-title=\"Location\"(.*?)tr>").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of removing what you don't want, consider keeping what you do want.

It makes for easier code to read in the future too, as your code then shows what what you are interested of.

Comment: Yes, but if i search for each `<td>...</td>` that's its what i wont i don't get a result with all `<tds>` for each row, i will get a result for each `<td>`

Comment: IIRC there is a possibility to keep the filter-string in the result.